# Passing variables from flow to apex and then from apex to flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, knowledge, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I'm trying to put in place a screen flow component in order to display knowledge articles based on the case fields and Knowledge-articles data category.

In order to do so, I've created an apex class that I use to query for my KnowledgeArticleVersion that I will be using in my flow.

Here's my Apex Class:

```
public class KnowledgeArticleLookup {

   public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> getMyArticles (){
     
     string varType1;
     string varType2;
     List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> Articles = new List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>();
   
    if(varType1 == 'Global Info'){
        If(varType2 == 'Location'){
                Articles = [SELECT Id,Title FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion WHERE PublishStatus='online' with DATA CATEGORY Global_Knowledge__c AT Location__c];
        }
     }
      return Articles;
 }
```

Knowing that vartype1 and vartype2 are values used in my flow ( in a get element), I was wondering how I can pass these two variables to my apex class and how I can pass my Articles(list) to my Flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an input and output from flow to apex or vice versa, you will need to ensure you annotate them as `@InvocableVariable`.

To make your apex method available as an action, annotate the method with  `@InvocableMethod`

So here is how you will modify your apex,

```
public class KnowledgeArticleLookup {

   @InvocableMethod(label='Get Knowledge Articles' description='Gets knowledge article results')
   public static List<List<Response>> getMyArticles (List<Request> req){
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> Articles = new List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>();

    if(req[0].varType1 == 'Global Info'){
      if(req[0].varType2 == 'Location'){
            articles = [SELECT Id,
                              Title 
                             FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
                             WHERE PublishStatus='online' 
                             WITH DATA CATEGORY 
                             Global_Knowledge__c AT Location__c];
      }
    }
    List<List<Response>> outputResponse = new List<List<Response>>();
    List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();
    for(KnowledgeArticleVersion kav: articles) {
         Response response = new Response();
         response.articleversionId = kav.Id;
         response.articleTitle = kav.Title;
         responses.add(response);
    }
    outputResponse.add(responses);
   return outputResponse;
  }

  public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String varType1;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
     public String varType2;
   }

   public class Response {
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleversionId;
      @InvocableVariable
       public String articleTitle;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mohith,
Thanks for your response.
I copied and pasted the code that you provided. However, I get the following error :
Illegal conversion from Object to List<List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>>

Comment: btw, methods with @Invocable annotation accept only one parameter

Comment: You can create a wrapper class for response and request and that should be good enough to fix these. Hope that helps

Comment: I did create my wrapper class which looks like this:
     public class Request{
         
         @InvocableVariable(required=true)
         public String varType1;
         @InvocableVariable(required=true)
         public String varType2;

      }
    
    public class Result{

        @InvocableVariable
          public List<List<KnowledgeArticleVersion>> outputResponse; 
 }
but what should i put as a return value? i'm confused.

Comment: I did update the answer with wrapper

Comment: Inside the `for` loop, shouldn't it be `response.articleversionId = kav.Id;` and `response.articleTitle = kav.Title;`? That, or change the variable names inside the `Response` class?

Comment: @Moonpie Good catch sir! Fixed!

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava, thanks for your answers.
The invocable methode accepts only a List type Parameter. And I'm not able to set my output variable in my flow.

Comment: Just changed the input to list.See if that helps

Comment: Check your query and make sure it does return records.

Comment: Thanks @MohithShrivastava